# Не могу через указатель прочитать поле структуры

Tags: c, структуры

Есть у меня структура вида:

```
typedef union{
    uint16_t word[32];
    struct{
        uint8_t Ho[32];
        uint8_t Lo[32];
    };
} _DIO_MIN; 


typedef union{
    uint16_t word[128];
    struct{
        uint8_t Ho[128];
        uint8_t Lo[128];
    };
} _DIO_MID; 


typedef union{
    uint16_t word[4096];
    struct{
        uint8_t Ho[4096];
        uint8_t Lo[4096];
    };
} _DIO_MAX;


typedef struct DIO{
       unionDio DIO00;
       _DIO_MIN DIO_MIN[63];      
       _DIO_MID DIO_MID[32];     
       _DIO_MAX DIO_MAX[4];       
       float    GLOB[8192];
       uint16_t ASUIO[32768];
       uint8_t  LOCALL[32768];
       float    STATDATA[32768];
       char     ERRORS[80];
       int      READYINPUT; 
    

       char     DISP1[2][30][95];
       char     DISP2[2][30][95];
       char     DISP3[2][30][95];
       char     DISP4[2][30][95];
} _SysMem;

extern _SysMem SYSMEM;
```

Хочу по байтно обращаться через указатель к полям структуры для этого  делаю:

```
uint8_t *addrSYSMEM = NULL;
addrSYSMEM = (uint8_t*)&SYSMEM;
SYSMEM.GLOB[0] = 16;
float a = *(addrSYSMEM + 45056);
```

Но в 'a' равно нулю. Не могу понять где не прав.

Comment: А что такое `unionDio`? Какой у него размер?

Comment: А что если `float a = *(addrSYSMEM + 45056);` заменить на `float a = *((float *)addrSYSMEM + 45056);`?

Comment: https://ideone.com/SQH6t4 ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сначала нужно не забывать поменять тип указателя. А так-же в структурах сначала нужно узнать место элемента. Оно всегда упорядочено компилятором и тот добавляет пустые места (*выравнивает*).

Узнать смещение поля :

```
# include <stddef.h>
size_t const of_GLOB = offsetof ( _SysMem , GLOB ) ;
```

и тогда первый `float` можно получить :

```
float a = * ( float * ) (addrSYSMEM + of_GLOB);
```

И это ещё не всё. Побайтовый доступ конфликтует с оптимизацией компилятора. Он может удалить все "ненужные" присваивания и **не** считывать свежие значения, так-как думает, что ничего не изменилось. По-этому всегда делайте переменную `volatile`.

```
extern volatile _SysMem SYSMEM;
volatile _SysMem SYSMEM;
```

Answer (score 0):

В Вашем случаи использование статичного смешение будет плохо переносимым способом.
Попробуйте проверить корректность Вашего смешения.

```
uint8_t *addrSYSMEM = (uint8_t*)&SYSMEM;
SYSMEM.GLOB[0] = 16.0;
int off = (int)&SYSMEM.GLOB - (int)&SYSMEM;
float a = *(float*)(addrSYSMEM + off);
```

Answer (score 0):

Все дело в том что возможно на вашей машине *(как и на моей)*, порядок байт в машинном слове расположен как [**Little Endian**](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BA_%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2).

```
int main(void) {
    float a = 16.f;

    unsigned char *b = (unsigned char *) &a;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(float); i++) {
        printf("%d,", b[i]);
    }

    printf("\b\0\n"); /* удалить лишнюю запятую, и добавить перенос строки */
}
```

> `0, 0, 128, 65`

Как вы видите, первый байт, равен нулю, отсюда у вас и берется тот самый нуль, т.к. вы приводите тип `uint8_t` к `float` aka `((float)((int8_t)0)) ~~ .0f`, сам же `float` это совокупность 4х байт.

Но если же следовать примеру из комментариев который я оставил, то там ясно видно, что при приведении типа к оригинальному типу, его размерность будет правильно понята компилятором, и он будет копировать не 1й байт из указателя на `int8_t`, а `sizeof(float) == 4`.

Подробнее читайте на просторах.